# Powershell Remove-Item get Loggingfile

Tags: powershell, logging

i have probably searched the whole web, but I'm not able to help myself. Otherwise I'm just incapable.
All I want is to delete folders after 30 days and display the results in a simple .log file.

```
dir "C:\Users\sam\Desktop\Files_todelete\*" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where { ((Get-Date) - $_.LastWriteTime).days -gt 30 } | Remove-Item -Recurse
```

This works for me, but I tried nearly everything to log the results.
Hopefully you can help me to fix this issue.

Comment: It needs to be a oneliner?

Comment: No, not necessary. But I am not that fit to implement different functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include logging part to your script. You can make `foreach loop` for every item that needs to be removed and write down activity to log file. Here is an example:

```
$LogFile = 'C:\log.txt'
dir "C:\Users\sam\Desktop\Files_todelete\*" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
    Where { ((Get-Date) - $_.LastWriteTime).days -gt 30 } | 
        ForEach-Object {
            Remove-Item $_.FullName -Recurse
            Out-File -InputObject $('Removed {0}' -f $_.FullName) -FilePath $LogFile -Append
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! You made my day, this is what I was searching for!

Answer (score 0):

So in this case it worked for me, but I want to use the Script for network drives. If I edit the path everything seems to be fine. But the problem here is the permission. Therefore I found a solution with Get-ChildItem -Directory.
My question here is can pipe this in front of the Remove-Item command?

Like:

$LogFile = '\netshare\folder\log.txt'

dir "\netshare\Files_todelete*" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |

Where { ((Get-Date) - $_.LastWriteTime).days -gt 30 } |

ForEach-Object {

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory | Remove-Item $_.FullName -Recurse
        Out-File -InputObject $('Removed {0}' -f $_.FullName) -FilePath $LogFile -Append
    }
```

Logically the Get-ChildItem needs to be in front of the loop?! But I'm not that firm to edit the beginning of the loop correctly.